# How can I stop this from over writing the data and adding it to last row in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import data from a csv file, the script works as it brings the data in but over wright the data already in my sheet, please how do I get this script to insert in the next available row also how do I only fetch from row 3?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}

function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Google Drive to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");
   
  var searchTerm = "title = '"+fileName+"'";

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchTerm)
  var csvFile = "";
   

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      break;
    }
  }

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
}
```

Comment: I have got last row with
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
but still trying to figure out only to fetch data from row 3
Tar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

1. To insert the data in the next available row:

   ```
   sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
   ```
2. You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get from the third row onwards:

   ```
   csvData.slice(2);
   ```

---

### Solution:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}

function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Google Drive to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");
   
  var searchTerm = "title = '"+fileName+"'";

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchTerm)
  var csvFile = "";
   

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      break;
    }
  }

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var s_csvData = csvData.slice(2); // <- new code
  
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, s_csvData.length, s_csvData[0].length).setValues(s_csvData); // <- modification
}
```

Comment: The solution didn´t work, well it did ignore the first 2 rows but that was after reading it, the problem is the the first row only has data in cell 1 and the second row is empty so it cant parse it so I need the script to only read from row 3 and not miss writing it

Comment: The `Logger.log(csvData)` to show us it's structure. Also what you just asked it is not part of your original question and you don't provide enough information to help us help you. Also, it is not a good behaviour to unaccept an answer that solved the issue you mentioned in the original question. If you have other issues then post a different question, don't unaccept the answer that solved you original one. @JohnnyCardel

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the question at the end of my question "also how do I only fetch from row 3."

Comment: Yes and this is what it does. If the csv file is broken or has missing rows or the parser you are using is wrong, then you need to specify it or ask a different question. Anyway, good luck :) @JohnnyCardel

Comment: it logs the following:
[20-10-17 15:06:59:877 BST] [[4], [0], [obj], [<<], [/Type], [/Catalog], [/Names], [<<], [/JavaScript], [3], [0], [R], [>>], [/PageLabels], [<<], [/Nums], [[], [0], [<<], [/S], [/D], [/St], [1], [>>], []], [>>], [/Outlines], [2], [0], [R], [/Pages], [1], [0], [R], [>>], [endobj], [5], [0], [obj], [<<], [/Creator], [(��]]

and only puts data in col a

Comment: What is your delimeter ? If the delimeter is `/` then try `Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile,'/')` or use `,`